# Drawing navigation path on ImageView using Canvas

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-bitmap, android-paint

In my application, I need to show navigation path between an array of points on `ImageView` using `Canvas`. I am able to draw a path on an `ImageView` but I need to draw similar to this image:

[image: Navigation path image]

Is it possible to draw a navigation path like this using `Canvas` on `ImageView`?

Please guide me on this concept.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nipun_floor_temp);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
Bitmap drawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
// Line
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
int startx = 340;
int starty = 103;
int endx = 340;
int endy = 503;
canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);

imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), drawBitmap));
```

Comment: sure: make a custom `BitmapDrawable` class and override its `draw` method

Comment: Thank you for reply, can you suggest some links to achieve that?

Comment: links on how to extend some class in java and override one or more methods?

Comment: No, any sample code reference links.

Comment: here you have reference link for [Drawable#draw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method